# Create TableView objects with UI or programmatically?

Tags: ios, uitableview, storyboard

Who is the best optimized way?

Create objects in my UITableView using storyboard (Drag and drop in my cell), or create objects programmatically (cellForRowAtIndexPath)?

When the project compile and run in device which of the two options will run faster?

Comment: Try it an see which is faster.

Comment: @maddy How can I do this and show the result in seconds on console log?

Comment: Get the current time in your `init...` method and at the end of `viewDidAppear:`.

Comment: Why does it matter? Are iPhone so slow that the user is going to notice any difference whatsoever?No.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In terms of pure performance, code created UI objects are faster than any nibs / storyboards objects, only because storyboards and nibs files are stored on disk until they are loaded in memory and translated in UIKit objects.

That being said, it also depends on how you are implementing it. If you use prototype cells in storyboard vs creating cells everytime in cellForRowAtIndexPath, then storyboards win because of the reuse cells (though you can also reuse code created cells).

And that being said again, the performance win you have by creating UI with code is ver small and not even close to be perceptible by the human eye. Therefore, for me, using the storyboard is a no brainer for the ease of creating interface without polluting your code.

You can see a nice article about that here: http://www.toptal.com/ios/ios-user-interfaces-storyboards-vs-nibs-vs-custom-code. The article is approx. 1 year old but it still is accurate.

Answer (score 1):

The effective performance will be identical for the same layouts. I would choose one approach over the other based on different needs.

Storyboard prototype cells can be faster to setup, easier to get Autolayout constraints working correctly, but *you cannot re-use that prototype cell outside of its Storyboard*. If using the same cell layout across multiple views is required, writing your table view cell in code or using a nib file is required.

Also, it should be pointed out that `cellForRowAtIndexPath` is still required when using a Storyboard prototype cell in order to configure your cells, assuming you have some sort of dynamic data to display. Similarly, in the programmatic approach you should not be *creating* views in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` but rather configuring them.